# How to create empty game object in canvas on unity?

Tags: unity

Whenever I set up my main menu and put them in an empty gameobject inside the canvas so I can turn it off to switch menu It messes up the gui inside device simulators on several phones. In short it doesn't scale with the phone screen size whenever its inside an empty gameobject in canvas?

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured the RectTransform of the empty game object?

Comment: @DMGregory https://prnt.sc/1zprmth

Comment: You've configured this object to have a fixed width and height and stay centered on the canvas. Have you tried [using the stretch options under the Anchor Presets panel and setting the anchor and position fields as explained in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html)?